# Ion Json Android

Tags: android

Estou trabalhando com esta biblioteca https://github.com/koush/ion e não estou conseguindo manipular o retorno dos dados via JSON do seguinte formato

```
[{"id":"1","nome":"XXX","cidade":"XXXXXXX"},{"id":"2","nome":"XXXX","cidade":"XX‌​XXXXXXXX"}] 

JsonObject json = new JsonObject();

Ion.with(context)
.load("http://example.com/post")
.setJsonObjectBody(json)
.asJsonObject()
.setCallback(new FutureCallback<JsonObject>() {
   @Override
    public void onCompleted(Exception e, JsonObject result) {
       // COMO TRABALHAR ELES AQUI????
    }
});
```

Comment: Você conseguiu esclarecer essa dúvida? Porque também não consigo trabalhar dentro do: public void onCompleted(Exception e, JsonObject result) { quando utilizo a estrutura Ion dentro de um método que instanciarei em outra classe.

Answer (score -1):

Neste caso, você precisa pegar o retorno como `.asJsonArray()` e não como `.asJsonObject()`.